# I want to split the bitmap with for loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, split, bitmap, grid

I wanted to split the bitmap with code, I succeeded, but what I want to do is to achieve this with a for loop, that is, I want to divide the bitmap numbered in the picture and transfer it to the Arraylist, I achieved this using the code below, but as I said I want to do it with a for loop.

[click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHTOc.jpg)

```
bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)0, (int)0, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)0, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap3 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)(2 * (bitmap.getWidth() / 3)), (int)0, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap4 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)0, (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap5 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap6 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)(2 * (bitmap.getWidth() / 3)), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap7 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)0, (int)(2 * (bitmap.getHeight() / 3)), (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3)); 

bitmap8 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(2 * (bitmap.getHeight() / 3)), (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3));

bitmap9 = Bitmap.createBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap, (int)(2 * (bitmap.getWidth() / 3)), (int)(2 * (bitmap.getHeight() / 3)), (int)(bitmap.getWidth() / 3), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() / 3));
```

Comment: Please check this link - http://www.chansek.com/splittingdividing-image-into-smaller/

Comment: @AndroidGeek thanks for the answer, i got what i wanted